# Delete a node after X weeks it was created

Tags: nodes, 8

How  can I delete a node after, for example, 2 weeks it has been created?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're looking for a developer-centric solution, you can invoke [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.2.x) in a custom module to clean up old nodes:

```
function MYMODULE_cron() {

  // Other conditions can be altered/added as neeed
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('created', strtotime('-2 week'), '<=');
  $nids = $query->execute();
  foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $node->delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Using $nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids) and then $storage->deleteMultiple($nodes) is bit faster, but unless you're deleting dozens of nodes, not a big issue.

Comment: I would create a queue based approach for scaling out. You don't need Rules.

Answer (score 4):

Based off Shawn Conn's answer, here is the full solution for novices:

1. Go to your root file directory and create folder "delete_old_nodes"
2. Create a file in the folder you just created called: "delete_old_nodes.info.yml" and paste this code in it:

   ```
   name: Delete old nodes
   description: Deletes nodes older than 30 days.
   package: Custom
   type: module
   version: 1.0
   core: 8.x
   ```
3. Create a file called "delete_old_nodes.module" and put this code into it:

   ```
   <?php

   function delete_old_nodes_cron() {

     $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
       ->condition('created', strtotime('-2 week'), '<='); // Can change -2 week to -2 year or -3 day
     $nids = $query->execute();
     foreach ($nids as $nid) {
       $node = node_load($nid);
       $node->delete();
     }
   }
   ```
4. Flush cache, then navigate to modules page — (yoursite.com/admin/modules) —  and enable your module, (by searching for "delete old nodes", click the checkbox by the modules name and click save).
5. Done! Whenever you run cron, the nodes/pages that were published -2 weeks, or whatever you have it at, from now will be deleted.
6. Note: To schedule when cron runs, go to yoursite.com/admin/config/system/cron

Testing:

Create a node and change the published date, normally in the right sidebar, to -2 weeks or whatever you have it at. Manually run cron at yoursite.com/admin/config/system/cron and you should not be able to find your node.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `hook_cron()` implementation too, but using the following code.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->accessCheck(FALSE)
    ->condition('created', strtotime('-2 week'), '<=');
  $result = $query->execute();
  if (!empty($result)) {
    $nids = array_keys($result);
    $nodes = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($nids);
    $storage_handler->delete($nodes);
  }
}
```

The code I used to delete the nodes is the one that the deprecation message for [`entity_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_delete_multiple/8.7.x) suggests to use.
I also used a call to `accessCheck(FALSE)` to avoid the entity query returns only the nodes to which the anonymous user has access. (Cron tasks run as anonymous user.)

If then there is the possibility the nodes to delete are too much, I would limit the number of nodes deleted each time cron tasks run.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->accessCheck(FALSE)
    ->condition('created', strtotime('-2 week'), '<=')
    ->range(0,30);
  $result = $query->execute();
  if (!empty($result)) {
    $nids = array_keys($result);
    $nodes = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($nids);
    $storage_handler->delete($nodes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do try to do it as such:

1. Create a View of all nodes that are 2+ weeks old
2. Create a system Rule to run on Cron maintenance
3. In the rule configuration, create a loop to iterate over those view results
4. Delete each node

I'll try to test it when I get a chance, because I'm not entirely sure how easy/possible it'll be to utilize the view like that in 3., but that's definitely where I'd start. Of course, this comes with the caveat that it won't delete nodes when the become EXACTLY 2 weeks old, but will be dependent on when Cron runs on your system; but, I assume within 3 hours or so is still sufficient.

(I only just noticed this was for D8; I think the process is still sound though.)

Comment: I didn't realize D8 until after I typed that. I just know rules are are in alpha for stable for D8; haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I went with the dev version of Rules. For what I was trying, it seemed stable, but I'm stuck at the fact that there seems to be no--planned otherwise--D8 version of the Views Rules module to use to loop over the view results. If there's a way to get Views in a Rule that I can't think of, it might work. Otherwise, I'm not sure.