# How can I remove old articles?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a Drupal 7 database that stores articles since 2013. The database is too big and I want to drop all the old articles to keep only the ones created on 2019, just for development purpose. I read [Delete a node after X weeks it was created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201724/delete-a-node-after-x-weeks-it-was-created/213647?noredirect=1#comment343284_213647), which describes what to do on Drupal 8. Is there a similar method for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous solutions offered by [@berramou](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/84694/berramou) and [@kiamlaluno♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno) should serve you well. On the other hand, if you're looking for a step by step solution, it's the following:

Based on [@kiamlaluno♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/84694/berramou)'s answer, here is the full solution for novices:

1. Go to your file directory and go to `/sites/all/modules`. Create a folder here called `delete_old_nodes`
2. Create a file in the folder you just created called: "delete_old_nodes.info" and paste this code in it:

   ```
   name = Delete old nodes
   description = Deletes nodes older than 30 days.
   package = Custom
   version = 1.0
   core = 7.x
   ```
3. Create a file called "delete_old_nodes.module" and paste [@kiamlaluno♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/84694/berramou)'s code into it:

   ```
   <?php

   function mymodule_cron() {
      $entity_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $entity_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
        ->entityCondition('created', strtotime('1 January 2019'), '<')
        ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')
        ->range(0, 25);
      $result = $entity_query->execute();
      if (isset($result['node'])) {
        node_delete_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
      }
   }
   ```
4. Flush cache, then navigate to modules page, `yoursite.com/admin/modules`, and enable your module, (by searching for "delete old nodes", click the checkbox by the modules name and click save).
5. When you want to **delete** all the nodes up to 1 January 2019, run cron by going to `yoursite.com/admin/reports/status/run-cron`.
6. Go back to the modules page, `yoursite.com/admin/modules`, and disable the module "delete old nodes".
7. Upvote [@kiamlaluno♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/84694/berramou)'s answer.
8. Done!

Answer (score 3):

The code I would use is similar to the following one.

```
$entity_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entity_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->entityCondition('created', strtotime('1 January 2019'), '<')
  ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT');
$result = $entity_query->execute();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  node_delete_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

The differences between the code I am using and the code shown in the answers for [Delete a node after X weeks it was created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201724/delete-a-node-after-x-weeks-it-was-created/213647) are the following:

- The object used to query the entity is instantiated differently and its class is different
- The code doesn't select just the published nodes (I take you are interested in deleting all the nodes created before 2019)
- The code is using `addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')` to get all the nodes, even the ones to which the currently logged-in user doesn't have access (Remember that cron tasks are executed as anonymous user, which possibly doesn't have access to many of the nodes)
- In Drupal 7, the functions to delete nodes are [`node_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7.x) and [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7.x) which require, respectively, a node ID and an array of node IDs

If I were to do the task in a `hook_cron()` implementation, I would use the following code.

```
  function mymodule_cron() {
    $entity_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entity_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
      ->entityCondition('created', strtotime('1 January 2019'), '<')
      ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')
      ->range(0, 25);
    $result = $entity_query->execute();
    if (isset($result['node'])) {
      node_delete_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
    }
  }
```

Older Drupal 7 versions would need to replace `addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')` with `addMetaData('account', user_load(1))`. For those versions the code would be then similar to the following one.

```
  function mymodule_cron() {
    $entity_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entity_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
      ->entityCondition('created', strtotime('1 January 2019'), '<')
      ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1))
      ->range(0, 25);
    $result = $entity_query->execute();
    if (isset($result['node'])) {
      node_delete_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
    }
  }
```

Using `hook_cron()` avoids issues in the case there are many nodes to delete. Trying to load, for example, 3000 nodes (even if the `EntityFieldQuery` class returns partially loaded nodes) could cause memory or timeout errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you there is a similar method to do so you can use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x)

Here is a helper function to delete all `articles` older than two weeks.
You can use it as `drush command` or in `cron_hook` as it described in the mentioned question.

```
function delete_older_articles(){
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
    ->entityCondition('created', strtotime('-2 week'), '<=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED);
  $result = $query->execute();
  foreach ($result['node'] as $nid => $node) {
    node_delete($nid);
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I run it as a drush command?